# c# mongodb collection count and find document result from asqueryable

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-query

In my C# console application project I'm using MongoDB.Driver.2.4.3 with connection to MongoDB 3.2.10.

How do I count the number of documents, find the first and the last document from the filtered query?

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        DateTime myTimeConvert = DateTime.Now;

        var client = new MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:27017");
        var DB = client.GetDatabase("football");

        var players = DB.GetCollection<Player>("players");


        var playersInBrazil = players.AsQueryable()
                         .Where(p => p.country == "Brazil");
        //count the number of documents and find the first and the last document from the filtered query 

    }

    internal class Player
    {
        public ObjectId Id { get; set; }
        public string firstname { get; set; }
        public BsonDateTime birthdate { get; set; }
        public string country { get; set; }
        public double goals { get; set; }
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var countPlayersInBrazil = players.AsQueryable().Count(p => p.country == "Brazil");
var firstPlayersInBrazil = players.AsQueryable().First(p => p.country == "Brazil");
var lastPlayersInBrazil = players.AsQueryable().Last(p => p.country == "Brazil");
```

Comment: thanks - the countPlayersInBrazil and firstPlayersInBrazil variables works, but for lastPlayersInBrazil I get the error: Unhandled Exception: System.NotSupportedException: The method Last is not supported in the expression tree: aggregate([]).Last(p => (p.country == "Brazil")).

Comment: I should add I ran these to test the variables.Console.WriteLine(countPlayersInBrazil);
            Console.WriteLine(firstPlayersInBrazil.firstname);
            Console.WriteLine(lastPlayersInBrazil.firstname);

Comment: I would doubt that First is supported but Last isn't. I guess you would like to get this working sp do the following. players.AsQueryable().Where(p => p.country == "Brazil").ToList(). Then do the count, first last on that. Then you've left the mongo world. Not the most effective but hey there shouldn't be that many players in Brazil :)